# Vector sort operator

Tags: vector-spaces, definition, sorting

I was wondering whether there exists a definition of the sort operator for vector, i.e., the operator that given a vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$ yields a vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose components are sorted in some order.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic

Comment: *Order statistics* have nothing whatsoever to do with the sort operation.  One needs a scalar for sorting, for instance length, length in some metric, length of a particular component, etc.  There is no unique way to order vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ unless $n=1$.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Why you said there is no unique way to order a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$?